# How can I test my policy? What after generate Balana jar files?

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, balana, wso2-identity-server

I have installed Balana correctly and run mvn clean install with no error,
How can I get benefit from Jar file?
How can I test the policy that I have written in XACML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Balana is just the engine. Once you Balana compiled (and presumably jarred), you need to start it and pass it the XACML policies you wrote. Now, at start-up, Balana should validate that the files are valid XACML 2.0 or XACML 3.0 files.

What you want to do next is send an authorization request using a tool e.g. SoapUI or Postman to the endpoint Balana exposes (if any that is). That will help you validate the endpoint.

PS: I have limited experience with Balana. I work mostly with Axiomatics Policy Server (disclaimer: it's where I work).

PS2: if you want to stay down the path of open source, check out AuthZForce. It's much more active.

Answer (score 1):

When WSO2 Implements open standard protocols like XACML, SCIM they do not tightly coupled implementation with WSO2 platform components. For EX: Balana for XACML [2], Charon for SCIM [1]. Inside WSO2 Identity Server [3] you will find two artifacts org.wso2.balana_1.1.5.jar, org.wso2.balana.utils_1.1.5.jar which are relevant to WSO2 XACML implementation. If you want to make use of Balana artifacts pls refer [4].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/charon

[2] https://github.com/wso2/balana

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/

[4] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Working+with+XACML